# Link to a section from bootstrap 4 modal nav

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a bootstrap modal for my mobile fullscreen navbar, and the links in the navbar are linking to sections of the page, but when clicking on the links in the modal no scrolling happens.

I've tried switching the href to `index.html#home` instead of `#home` with no success.

This is my modal:

```
<div
  class="modal fade fullscreen"
  id="menuModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close btn btn-link"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          aria-hidden="true">
          <i class="fa fa-close fa-lg"></i>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">
          <span class="sr-only">main navigation</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#home" data-dismiss="modal">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about" data-dismiss="modal">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact" data-dismiss="modal">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the links in the navbar to smooth-scroll to the desired section of the page.
I have made an example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dimabran/pen/yLLKJKd)

Comment: Do you have a working example of your code?
We dont have your CSS. You can use something like jsfiddle to create an example

Comment: @Andrew I have added a Codepen.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to do that without javascript. Are you open to using js to trigger the scroll to the hash anchor?

Comment: That's not possible without javascript. But, if you really don't want to use JS here, remove the `data-dismiss="modal"` from your `modal-body` anchors. But in this case, you will have to dismiss the modal by yourself after the scroll happens.

Comment: How can i dismiss the modal after the scroll happens? using js is fine.

Comment: Here's quick and dirty fork of your pen to show the concept -- https://codepen.io/iskandarreza/pen/abbYBoj